# Migrate some parts of an old git repo to a new one including relevant commit history

Tags: git

I have an old git repo with multiple directories, each representing an own project (for instance Project A, Project B and Project C.

Now, I need to migrate the Project A to a completely new repo, which will be dedicated to Project A only.

All commit history related to Project A should be migrated as well. But, the commits related to Project B and Project C should not be migrated.

What's the best way to accomplish this?